# Escape keywords with tmux send

Tags: tmux, arguments, escape-characters, terminal-multiplexer

Using `tmux` to send commands along from one terminal to another, I realize that

```
$ tmux send -t mySession "text" ENTER
```

correctly sends `text`, but

```
$ tmux send -t mySession "up" ENTER
```

sends `text` again, probably because `up` is interpreted not as text, but as keyworded key up arrow.

Similarly,

```
$ tmux send -t mySession "3" ENTER
```

correctly sends `3`, but

```
$ tmux send -t mySession "-3" ENTER
tmux: unknown option -- 3
usage: send-keys [-lRM] [-t target-pane] key
```

fails with this error message, and this naive try to escape

```
$ tmux send -t mySession "\-3" ENTER
```

sends `3` again, not the expected `-3`.

Anyway, I'm pretty sure that I've missed something about the way tmux interprets and understand its argument. What am I missing here?

How do I ensure that `mytmuxcommand "<text>" ENTER` will always be interpreted as *"send actual `<text>` then send ENTER key"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send a string literally you can use the `-l` option to `send-keys`, but as you might still have more options after the `-l` you need to use something like `''` (an empty string) to no longer be looking for options beginning `-`.

You cannot mix and match the literal with keynames like Enter, so finally you need to give two commands, eg:

```
tmux send-keys -t session -l '' -3 \; send-keys -t session Enter
```

Comment: That really is heplful, cheers :) Don't forget to wrap your `<text>` in quotes because `tmux send-keys -t session -l '' two words` actually sends `twowords`, but `tmux send-keys -t session -l '' "up down"` does send `up down` as expected :)